# How to run specific date query for a range of dates

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

**Tables**

```
table1 (mdate date, id1 number, id2 number, id3 number, description varchar2);--activity table 
table2 (id1 number ,id2 number, id3 number,flag number);                      --customer table
```

`(id1, id2 , id3)` is a key in `table2` and a foreign key in `table1`.

Here is a query that runs for a specific date (`:mydate`), and returns rows from `table1` (activities) that have been idle for a period of 2 months and then reemerged on the given date (`:mydate`).

```
select mdate, id3, id1, id2, description  
from table2 where (id1,id2, id3) in  
(
  select  id1,id2, id3  from table1 where --get the keys with flag=1 and no activity for 2 months 
    flag=1 and 
    not exists --no activity for 2 months before :mydate (not counting mydate) 
        (
            select 1 from  table2  where  
            mdate>=add_months(to_date(:mydate,'dd/mm/rrrr'),-2) --- activity 2 months ago  
            and mdate < to_date( :mydate,'dd/mm/rrrr') --- but not the given day   
            and table1.id1 =table2.id1 and table1.id2 = table2.id2 and table1.id3 = table2.id3
        )
    and exists 
        (
            select 1 from  table2  where    
            mdate = to_date( :mydate,'dd/mm/rrrr') -- activity on given day ( mydate)
            and table1.id1 =table2.id1 and table1.id2 = table2.id2 and table1.id3 = table2.id3
        )
 ) and mdate=:mydate --new activity
```

Thus, running for e.g. `01/06/2018` could give as a result

```
01/06/2018 1 1 1 'lights on'
01/06/2018 1 1 2 'power off'
01/06/2018 1 3 5 'sound off'
```

Now I need the same query to run for a range of dates e.g. from `01/06/2018` to `03/06/2018`

and the results should be

```
01/06/2018 1 1 1 'lights on'
01/06/2018 1 1 2 'power off'
01/06/2018 1 3 5 'sound off'

02/06/2018 1 5 1 'power on'
02/06/2018 1 7 2 'power off'
02/06/2018 1 9 5 'sound on'

03/06/2018 8 1 1 'lights off'
03/06/2018 5 1 2 'power  off'
03/06/2018 9 3 5 'sound  off'
```

It is like union all for 3 runs of the previous query. However I should be able to run this for whatever date range.

I can achieve the above by using pipe lined function - but I want a sql solution.
May be some sort of recursive / hierarchical sql ?

(I tried to use `connect by` and `level` but didn't get the required results)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a WITH clause to generate a table of dates in your range, like this:

```
with cte as ( 
    select :start_date + (level-1) as mydate
    from dual
    connect by level <= (:end_date - :start_date) +1
)
select mdate, id3, id1, id2, description  
from cte 
     join table2 on table2.mdate = cte.mydate --new activity 
where (id1,id2, id3) in  
(
  select  id1,id2, id3  from table1 where --get the keys with flag=1 and no activity for 2 months 
    flag=1 and 
    not exists --no activity for 2 months before :mydate (not counting mydate) 
        (
            select 1 from  table2  where  
            mdate>=add_months(to_date(cte.mydate,'dd/mm/rrrr'),-2) --- activity 2 months ago  
            and mdate < to_date( cte.mydate,'dd/mm/rrrr') --- but not the given day   
            and table1.id1 =table2.id1 and table1.id2 = table2.id2 and table1.id3 = table2.id3
        )
    and exists 
        (
            select 1 from  table2  where    
            mdate = to_date( cte.mydate,'dd/mm/rrrr') -- activity on given day ( mydate)
            and table1.id1 =table2.id1 and table1.id2 = table2.id2 and table1.id3 = table2.id3
        )
 )
```

---

Okay I just noticed your question says ...

> I tried to use `connect by` and `level` but didn't get the required results

... and this solution uses `connect by` and `level`. Hmmmm. With luck this solution is different from yours but if you still don't get the required results please post some more details.

Comment: I was so close ... but something got me confused. You really nailed it - as always ;-)  Thanks.